# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at require('./bootstrap') Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have compiled my stylesheets and javascript files using Laravel Mix, code is given below:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

// mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
//    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.babel([
    'public/js/plugins/loaders/pace.min.js',
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'public/js/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js',
    'public/js/plugins/ui/nicescroll.min.js',
    'public/js/plugins/ui/drilldown.js',
    'public/js/plugins/ui/fab.min.js',
    'public/js/plugins/forms/selects/select2.min.js',
    'public/js/plugins/forms/styling/uniform.min.js',
    'public/js/plugins/ui/moment/moment.min.js',
    'public/js/plugins/ui/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js',
    'public/js/core/app.js',
    'public/js/pages/user_pages_profile.js',
] , 'public/js/app.js');

mix.styles([
    'public/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css',
    'resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
    'public/css/core.css',
    'public/css/components.css',
    'public/css/colors.css',
],'public/css/app.css');
```

Below is my **app.js**

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap'); //complains on this line after compilation

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

It complains on the **required**,
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at app.js:354** , this is the compiled **app.js**
I have tried: 
1- **mix.scripts**
2- **mix.babel** (according to docs this will translate any ES2015 code to vanilla JavaScript that all browsers will understand.)
What am i missing here?

Comment: Can you add the exact error you get?

Comment: error is mentioned in the question, but also added it in description now.

Comment: Try to use **import** instead of **require**.

Comment: for **import** i have to **export** something in **bootstrap.js** , right?

Comment: Are you using Laravel 5.4 ?

Comment: **import './bootstrap';** added this code, now gives this error<br>Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: yes @HamedKamrava

Comment: Did you fined any solution? I am also getting save error.

Comment: hey I don't remember exactly the solution. But I think I was missing a babel preset, .babelrc file in Laravel project root.

Answer (score 0):

Your node version is most likely out of date. Node JS 6 was the first version to handle ES2015 modules. Check your Node version by running

```
node -v
```

If you are using Ubuntu 16, you need to add a source repository to pull a newer version of node. Running the following commands should get you up to the latest version

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo npm update -g npm 
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Now try running **npm run dev** and everything should compile fine in Laravel mix.

Comment: its node v7.5.0

Comment: Thats odd. Should recognize the require directive if Node 7. Did you try wiping node_modules and re-running npm install?

Comment: It was a fresh install. let me do this again

Comment: I'm stumped if that doesn't fix it. Had the same issue is you at one point and the node upgrade plus reinstall fixed it. Hope it works!

Comment: didnt't fix it. i am using mix.babel and not mix.js, i tried writing both, meaning both mix.js and mix.babel in webpack.mix.js and then i got into jQuery not defined.